# Passing email content into an Azure Function App

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I want to pass the contents of an email into my Function App in order to remove HTML.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) but I'm puzzled at how the incoming email is passed in. I know that it is a http request but not sure which line is dealing with this email that we can then do work on.

We have our req which is our http request so I'm guessing that once we create the trigger in Azure, req is passed straight in?

This the example code that is provided:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {

   log.LogInformation("HttpWebhook triggered");

   // Parse query parameter
   string emailBodyContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

   // Replace HTML with other characters
   string updatedBody = Regex.Replace(emailBodyContent, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
   updatedBody = updatedBody.Replace("\\r\\n", " ");
   updatedBody = updatedBody.Replace(@"&nbsp;", " ");

   // Return cleaned text
   return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(new { updatedBody });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.Body` is the body of your HTTP message when you send a `POST` request to your Function. So the body of your request should contain your entire email content, then you should be good to go.

Actually your comment `// Parse query parameter` is wrong. It is not parsing a query parameter but reading the HTTP message body.

btw: I would advise you to do yourself a favor and not write C# Script Functions in the Azure Portal but write and test them locally, e.g. in VS Code, then compile them and deploy them properly to Azure Functions.

Comment: Cheers! Yeah i found its a bit of a nightmare writing in the portal. Thanks for the advice pal